# PyMySQL variables in queries

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to have a connection between my python code and a SQL database. I have read several ways to do it , but I am failing to get the results.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(user=X,passwd=X,host=X,port=X,database=X, charset='utf8', autocommit=True)
curs = conn.cursor()

try:
    curs.execute('SELECT id,sing_name,bir_yr FROM singers_list WHERE bir_yr = ? ',year)
    data = curs.fetchall()       
    for i in data:
        yield " Data: " + str(i) + "<br/>"
except:
    yield " Failed to get data from base<br/>"
```

Where **year** is an int python variable. I am getting the proper results with:

```
curs.execute('SELECT id,sing_name,bir_yr FROM singers_list)
```

Which means I am connecting successfully to the database . How can I include variables in queries ? (not only integers , but strings too or any type)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass the parameters inside an iterable - commonly a tuple:

```
query = 'SELECT id,sing_name,bir_yr FROM singers_list WHERE bir_yr = %s'
curs.execute(query, (year, ))
```

Note that I've also replaced the `?` placeholder with `%s`.

Also note that the MySQL driver *would automatically handle the type conversion* between Python and MySQL, would put quotes if necessary and escape the parameters to keep you safe from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Isn't using `?` kinda standard and used by everything excepted PyMySql?

Comment: @jlh I actually think it's the other way around :) Anyway, I usually just consult the driver documentation about the parameterization syntax. Thanks, good question.