# InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'Ihe' in 'where clause'")

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Below is a part of my python/pymysql code. I'm basically trying to retrieve data from a database using the input typed into a search box. I don't understand why the data typed in is coming across with this error. "Ihe" is simply a test hostname in my the database.

```
 @app.route('/result',methods= ['POST', 'GET'])
    def result():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                    result = request.form['hostname']
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
                    query = ("SELECT * FROM StoryData WHERE hostName LIKE %s" %  ( result))
                    cursor.execute(query)
                    search_for = cursor.fetchall()
                    for row in search_for:
                            ID = row['ID']
                            hName = row['hostName']
                            rName = row['reportName']

                    return render_template("result.html", search_for=search_for)
                    connection.close()
```

Comment: the query is incorrect. you need to quote the `LIKE` parameter, like so: `"SELECT * FROM StoryData WHERE hostName LIKE '%s'" %  ( result)` EDIT: Since the `result` parameter is coming from the request, this API endpoint is open to SQL injection attacks. You might want to consider protecting against this, by using an ORM or using other techniques

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyMySQL variables in queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094159/pymysql-variables-in-queries)

Answer (score 1):

As written, this is a very dangerous SQL Injection vulnerability.

What happens when I submit a POST request with `hostname` set to

```
''; DROP TABLE StoryData;
```

?

---

Use parameterized queries instead of using Python string formatting. Assuming your [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) is `format`, you can pass the parameters to [`execute()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id16):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM StoryData WHERE hostName LIKE %s"
cursor.execute(query, (result, ))
```

Comment: Though I don't like xkcd, a link to https://xkcd.com/327/ is inevitable to complement such a clear and colorful explanation.

Comment: SQL is not my thing, didn't realize what I was doing there. How would I fix to use a parameterized query?

Comment: @TarasTataryn: updated with an example of how to use a parameterized query