# Pymysql table name from variable

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am using Python3 and PyMySQL `0.7.9`. Version of Mysql is `5.5.57`.

Using this query to fetch data from Mysql works:

```
cur.execute('SELECT date FROM Tablename1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')
```

I would like to get name of table from variable.
Reading Pymysql docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094159/pymysql-variables-in-queries) Stackoverflow post lead me to belive that this code should work:

```
dbtable = Tablename1
query = 'SELECT date FROM %s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'
cur.execute(query, (dbtable, ))
```

But this results in error:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Tablename1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1")
```

I also tried using quotes but got different error:

```
query = 'SELECT `date` FROM `%s` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1'
cur.execute(query, (dbtable, ))
```

Results in:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'Databasename.'Tablename1'' doesn't exist")
```

How should the query be changed to allow variable work?

Comment: your code always passing `'` character to sql statement.
So, your select will become `select * from 'tablename1'`. And then, you will have the syntax error.

Try to pass the table name directly in sql, like:

`query = ''SELECT date FROM {} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1".format(Tablename1)`

Comment: With that formatting I was able to make the query work.

Comment: @Abe This solution works perfectly, but doesn't it open possibility for sql injection?

Comment: @spencer741 unfortunately yes, I recommend to use and query builder like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and this kind of flaw could be avoided.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Like this :

```
dbtable = input("Table name: ")
query = "SELECT * FROM %s"%(dbtable)
cur.execute(query)

results = cur.fetchall()

for row in results:
print (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
```

Comment: This satisfies the stated problem, but in a way that's vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Using python 3.8, mariadb 10.2, pymysql

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT field FROM %s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' %(dbtable))
result = cur.fetchone()
```

Replace field and dbtable approriately

Comment: This method is vulnerable to sql injection. Please do not do this.

Comment: Risks associated with sql injection depend on the application.  It's important to be aware of the implications, but it is myopic to imagine everyone is building an app where this is a concern at the sql level.