# python pymysql - mysql commands with parameters

Tags: python, mysql, parameters, pymysql

I am new to python and I am struggling with mysql commands and parameters.  Specifically, I find that I must use the '%' to separate the command from the parameters:

The connection is included as comments only for informational purposes.

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    # db = pymysql.connect(
      # host="localhost",
      # user="root",
      # password="---------",
      # database="golf",
      # charset="utf8mb4",
      # cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
    # )
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("USE golf")

    mySQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='%s'"
    email = "test@test.com"

    cur.execute(mySQLQuery % (email,))
    return render_template("index.html")
```

The examples I have found seem to use a ',' instead of a '%', and, if I am not mistaken, a ',' may be recommended.  However I receive an error when I replace the '%' with a ',':

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test@test.com''' at line 1")
```

The only change I made was in the cur.execute command:

```
 cur.execute(mySQLQuery, (email,))
```

I recognize that my understanding may be incorrect and a '%' is acceptable.

Any guidance or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the ' from " ... email='%s' "

Make it just email = %s and use cur.execute(mySQLQuery, (email,))

Hope this helps

Here you can find a good example 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37094912/12474033